# _score() missing 1 required argument 'y_true'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I need to run AgglomerativeClustering method and my The code is,

```
model = AgglomerativeClustering()
params = {"n_clusters": [2,3,4]}
clf = GridSearchCV(model, params, n_jobs=1, cv=10, refit=False)
clf.fit(self.data, None)
```

Then I get the error saying "_score() missing 1 required argument 'y_true'". However for clustering there is no y. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you dont specifiy your scoring function in `GridSearchCV` it will use (based on the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)):

> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

Your estimator is `model` so it is: `AllgomerativeClustering`, and if we check up this [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html), there is no scoring function in it. On top you are missing the train/test split fo this kind of algorithm. Currently GridSearchCV is not designed to use clusterign algorithm, you can have a check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633383/how-can-gridsearchcv-be-used-for-clustering-meanshift-or-dbscan) how to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As there is no dependent variable in clustering what is the purpose of having a training set? How can we test the accuracy of clustering algorithm?

Comment: for unsupervised learning methods, there is no direct testing. There are some methods like the elbow-method how you can define how close the clusters should be..