# 'DBSCAN' object has no attribute 'predict' using GridSearchCV & Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, dbscan, gridsearchcv

I am using [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) library and building a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) from it.

This is the last (and main) part of pipeline that I build:

```py
preprocessor_steps = [('data_transformer', data_transformer),
                      ('reduce_dim', TruncatedSVD())]
preprocessor = Pipeline(steps=preprocessor_steps)

clustering_steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                    ('cluster', DummyEstimator())]
clustering = Pipeline(steps=clustering_steps)
```

`data_transformer` has steps like OneHotEncoder, KNNImputer, etc.

Now I have [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

```py
param_grid = [{
      'cluster': [KMeans()],
      'cluster__n_clusters': range(1, 11),
      'cluster__init': ['k-means++', 'random']
    },  
    {
      'cluster': [DBSCAN()],
      'cluster__eps': [0.5, 0.7, 1],
    }]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clustering, param_grid=param_grid, 
                           scoring='accuracy', verbose=2, n_jobs=1,
                           error_score='raise')
  
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It works perfectly fine for all the hyperparameters of [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) but fails for [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html). It gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DBSCAN' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I think this is because DBSCAN has ['fit_predict'](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.fit_predict) and not 'predict'. I don't want to change my layout (like finding best pipeline from GridSearchCV) because I have many more parameters and algorithms that I want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem with `AgglomerativeClustering`
and to resolve this, I use Wrapper like this:

```
class AgglomerativeClusteringWrapper(AgglomerativeClustering):
    def predict(self,X):
      return self.labels_.astype(int)
```

So you can change to DBSCAN and all will work.